# How to loop a matrix with a window in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, vectorization

I have a n-by-m matrix in Matlab and I would like to loop the matrix with a window of specific size and then do some calculations (e.g. mean, standard deviation) on the values inside the window. The following picture should explain my point:

[image]

So in the image I have a 2 x 2 window and I loop the window through the matrix. At each loop I calculate the mean for the values inside the window. The output would in this example return me a matrix containing the corresponding mean values. Any idea how this could be done? Are there any built in functions for this in Matlab?

Thank you for any help! =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) if you have the image processing toolbox.

Another option is using [`im2col`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) with the `'distinct'` block type:

```
B = mean(im2col(A,[m n],'distinct'));
```